# C# an error when passing an unassigned out argument

Tags: c#

I was wondering why I get an error in the following code? I am passing an unassigned integer `x` to `foo` using an `out` argument. I also assign a value to `x` before returning it to the calling method.

```
int x;
Foo(out x);
Console.ReadLine();
void Foo(out int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // x is 0
    y = 1; // Mutate y
    Console.WriteLine(x); // x is 1
}
```

This is strange because in the following code I can pass an unassigned string using similar principles and don't get back any errors.

```
string a;
Split("Stevie Ray Vaughn", out a, out _);
Console.WriteLine(a); 
void Split(string name, out string firstNames, out string lastName)
{
    int i = name.LastIndexOf(' ');
    firstNames = name.Substring(0, i);
    lastName = name.Substring(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x); // x is 0` - what makes you think that x is 0 here? You haven't assigned it any value yet

Comment: *"why I get an error"* - What's the error, and what does it tell you about the problem?

Comment: You also seem to expect the compiler to determine that `Foo` *will* be called with `Foo(out x)` before the method ever gets called with any other argument - the C# compiler does not perform such analysis (which would only be useful in a tiny amount of cases)

Comment: Notice how in your second snippet, you nowhere refer to `a` inside of `Split` ...

Comment: This is fair enough, x does not have any value. I took it out from a textbook example: ```class Test
{
    static int x;
    static void Main() { Foo (out x); }
    static void Foo (out int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (x); // x is 0
        y = 1; // Mutate y
        Console.WriteLine (x); // x is 1
    }
}``` But I don't understand why this would work and the code in the question doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Console.WriteLine` calls from inside the `Foo` method can't compile unless `x` is a field, and not a local variable in the calling method.

If `x` is a field, then it automatically gets initialized with its default value, and since it's an int, the default value is 0. So code like this kind of makes sense. It will compile and run as you expected:

```
class C 
{
    int x;

    public void M() {      
        Foo(out x);
    }
    
    void Foo(out int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x); // x is 0
        y = 1; // assing a value to y
        Console.WriteLine(x); // x is 1
    }
}
```

The output of this will indeed be 0 and 1 as you can see in this [SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAY1IF5SoBTAd1IGEAKASgG49yA6AWQ7d8uDC1J4A3nlKzSASyjBSAD2Ey5qAMylUAFlKD2pSXLkazsgGIB7G6xsRlKrhdIBfN2/2lb9x8qKygCe7G7SuJaamACcrC6cpAD0SaoKAM6kAAxuZsHUpJiJKYZORMB0pMG50XEJyakqGYVunrhteEA).

However, if `x` was a local variable in the calling method, you'll get compilation errors on the two lines in `Foo` that are attempting to use it:

> error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

[Here's the SharpLab demo of that.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAY1IF5SoBTAd1IGEAKASgG49yA6AWQ7d8uDC1J4A3nlKzSqAMzyALKUHtSkuXJna5ASyjBSAD2F65AMQD211tYjGTXXbIC+ribm2pVNuw7GhsYAnuye0t4W8pgAnKzOnF7RpCHUpJhJnj5xCVzJch64RXhAA==)

Now suppose you'll change the `x` in these lines to `y`:

```
class C 
{
    public void M() {      
        int x;
        Foo(out x);
    }
    
    void Foo(out int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        y = 1; 
        Console.WriteLine(y); 
    }
}
```

Here's what will happen: You'll get an error on the first line calling `Console.WriteLine(y);`

> error CS0269: Use of unassigned out parameter 'y'

[Demo here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAY1IF5SoBTAd1IGEAKASgG49yA6AWQ7d8uDC1J4A3nlKzSqAMzyALKUHtSkuXJna5ASyjBSAD2F65AMQD211tYjGTXXbIC+ribm2pVNuw7GhsYAnuye0t4W8pgAnKxhnF7RpCHUpJhJnj5xCVzJch64RXhAA==)

But if you remove the first call to `Console.WriteLine(y);`, everything will work perfectly - as shown in [this demo.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAY1IF5SoBTAd1IGEAKASgG49yA6AWQ7d8uDC1J4A3nlKzSqAMzyALKUHtSkuXJna5ASyjBSAD2F65AMQD211tYjGTXXbIC+ribm2pVNuw7GhsYAnuye0t4WpCHUpJicXtHymACcrGGJnh64OXhAA==)

So, to conclude - the problem is not where you thought it was.
It's absolutely fine to pass down unassigned local variables as out parameters to methods, as long as you're not using them before their first assigned a value.